# insert XML element after another element using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml.etree

In Python 3.8 using the library xml.etree.ElementTree I'm trying to insert an XML element after another element.

So I have

```
<complaint>
    <name>First Last</name>
    <company>Some Company</company>
</complaint>
```

I'm trying to insert a new element after company but I can't use `.insert(1,newelement)` because the number of elements in complaint varies. So it might be 0, 1, 2, etc. Is there a way to lookup the index of the company element so I can add this new element after it?

Also when I create a new element with

`newElement = ET.Element('newElementName')`

it creates an element like `<newElementName></newElementName>`.

is there a way to tell it to just create it like `<newElementName/>`?

Comment: Yes, you can look up the index. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65523775/407651.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python write siblings in XML below desired tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65523775/python-write-siblings-in-xml-below-desired-tag)