# Python write siblings in XML below desired tag

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

I am trying to add some sibling tags after `<VIDPOM>10</VIDPOM>` tag

My XML looks like:

```
<ZAP>
    <N_ZAP>999</N_ZAP>
    <SLUCH>
      <IDCASE>100100100</IDCASE>
      <USL_OK>3</USL_OK>
      <VIDPOM>10</VIDPOM>
      <IDSP>99</IDSP>
      <USL>
        <IDSERV>123456789</IDSERV>
        <DATE_IN>2020-12-01</DATE_IN>
      </USL>
    </SLUCH>
</ZAP>
```

But I want to make it like this:

```
<ZAP>
    <N_ZAP>999</N_ZAP>
    <SLUCH>
      <IDCASE>100100100</IDCASE>
      <USL_OK>3</USL_OK>
      <VIDPOM>10</VIDPOM>
      <MY_CUSTOM_TAG>TEXT IS HERE</MY_CUSTOM_TAG>
      <IDSP>99</IDSP>
      <USL>
        <IDSERV>123456789</IDSERV>
        <DATE_IN>2020-12-01</DATE_IN>
      </USL>
    </SLUCH>
</ZAP>
```

My code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for SLUCH in root.iter('SLUCH'):
    IDCASE = SLUCH.find('IDCASE')
    VIDPOM = SLUCH.find('VIDPOM')
    print(IDCASE.text)
    print(VIDPOM.text)
    print()

    if IDCASE.text == "100100100":
        print('HERE')

        new_tag = ET.SubElement(VIDPOM, 'MY_CUSTOM_TAG')
        new_tag.text = 'TEXT IS HERE'
        
        tree.write('file_new.xml')
```

The output is:

```
<ZAP>
    <N_ZAP>999</N_ZAP>
    <SLUCH>
      <IDCASE>100100100</IDCASE>
      <USL_OK>3</USL_OK>
      <VIDPOM>10
        <MY_CUSTOM_TAG>TEXT IS HERE</MY_CUSTOM_TAG>
      </VIDPOM>
      <IDSP>99</IDSP>
      <USL>
        <IDSERV>123456789</IDSERV>
        <DATE_IN>2020-12-01</DATE_IN>
      </USL>
    </SLUCH>
</ZAP>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find position of `VIDPOM` in list of children of `SLUCH`

```
index = list(SLUCH).index(VIDPOM)  # deprecated: SLUCH.getchildren().index(VIDPOM)
```

and then you can `insert` one position after `VIDPOM`

```
SLUCH.insert(index+1, new_tag)
```

---

To format new element like `VIDPOM` (the same indentations) you can copy `tail`

```
new_tag.tail = VIDPOM.tail
```

---

Minimal working code - with data directly in code.

```
text ='''
<ZAP>
    <N_ZAP>999</N_ZAP>
    <SLUCH>
      <IDCASE>100100100</IDCASE>
      <USL_OK>3</USL_OK>
      <VIDPOM>10</VIDPOM>
      <IDSP>99</IDSP>
      <USL>
        <IDSERV>123456789</IDSERV>
        <DATE_IN>2020-12-01</DATE_IN>
      </USL>
    </SLUCH>
</ZAP>
'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
#root = tree.getroot()
root = ET.fromstring(text)

for SLUCH in root.iter('SLUCH'):
    VIDPOM = SLUCH.find('VIDPOM')

    new_tag = ET.Element('MY_CUSTOM_TAG')
    new_tag.text = 'TEXT IS HERE'
    new_tag.tail = VIDPOM.tail  # copy text after `tag`

    index = list(SLUCH).index(VIDPOM)
    #index = SLUCH.getchildren().index(VIDPOM)  # deprecated
    SLUCH.insert(index+1, new_tag)

print(ET.tostring(root).decode())
```

Result:

```
<ZAP>
    <N_ZAP>999</N_ZAP>
    <SLUCH>
      <IDCASE>100100100</IDCASE>
      <USL_OK>3</USL_OK>
      <VIDPOM>10</VIDPOM>
      <MY_CUSTOM_TAG>TEXT IS HERE</MY_CUSTOM_TAG>
      <IDSP>99</IDSP>
      <USL>
        <IDSERV>123456789</IDSERV>
        <DATE_IN>2020-12-01</DATE_IN>
      </USL>
    </SLUCH>
</ZAP>
```